# How to avoid showing the first value inside HTML Select tag

Tags: html

This is my simple HTML Select Program ,
by default its showing value as Volvo (the first value ) 
Is it possible that , not to show any value and let the user select ??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really simple. Just add a blank option:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
<select name="cars">
  <option></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a blank option to the first position.  Be sure to give it a value that you can then check for in your submit handler. EDIT: Or just use selectedIndex.
i.e.

```
if(document.getElementById("select1").selectedIndex != 0){
  form1.submit();
  }
else {alert("Please select a value!");}
```

to validate they have selected something.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="demo_form.asp">
<select id="select1"name="cars">
<option value="none"></option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I could +1 this if you show how `selectedValue` is obtained, and also if you display an error message if the form can't be submitted.

Comment: Done. I used "selectedIndex" as it is just easier.

Comment: Haha  oops I just realized I've used all my votes for today.  I'll try to remember to vote for this tomorrow!  :)  Or maybe some other member will lend me a vote.

Comment: You can borrow mine, i wan't it back though :) lmao

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1) Disable first item:

```
<select name="cars">
  <option value="" disabled>[Select an item]</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

2) Make first item empty, as already suggested.

```
<select name="cars">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just because it is disabled doesn't prevent the user from submitting the form.

Comment: @MichaelBray In any of the cases it does not. Obviously, extra JS is required for form validation.

Answer (score 0):

create a div (i called it "noShow"),

```
<div class="noShow">
    <form action="demo_form.asp">
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>    <!--  end noShow DIV
```

then, using Style sheets (CSS), apply this to the cars

```
.noShow option:first-child{
display:none;
```

try that, good luck

Comment: Why not apply the CSS to the `select` directly??  No need to introduce a `div` into this.  Also, this will hide the 'volvo' option.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "clean" way to do what you are asking - an HTML `select` will always display one of the values.

You can, however, include a 'Not Selected' option:

```
<option value=''>--Not Selected--</option>
```

but then you also have to do some validation to make sure that the user actually picks a valid value.  That's a topic for a different question.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to do something like this, if you also wanna provide some information:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
<select name="cars">
  <option value="default">Pick Something!</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```